# What can be said about the Chow rings of classifying spaces of semi-direct products of groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, motivic-cohomology, chow-groups

For instance, what can we say about the Chow ring of the classifying space of a semi-direct product $CH^*(B(G\ltimes H))$, in terms of the Chow rings of $CH^*(BG)$, $CH^*(BH)$, and the singular cohomology groups $H^*(BG,\mathbb{Z})$, $H^*(BH;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(B(G\ltimes H);\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: You might find some references in the book 
Group Cohomology and Algebraic Cycles by Burt Totaro.
E.g. Lemma 2.12 handles some wreath products.